# Why am I getting TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable error in my Program

Tags: python, for-loop, typeerror

My Program is

```
t = int(input()) # t is the number of Test cases
score = 0 
for i in t:
    for i in 10:
        c = input()
        d = list(c)
        if(d[0] == "X" or d[9] == "X"):
            score+=1
        if((i>0 and i<9) and (d[1] == "X" or d[8])):
            score+=2
        if((i>1 and i<8) and (d[2] == "X" or d[7])):
            score+=3
        if((i>2 and i<7) and (d[3] == "X" or d[6])):
            score+=4
        if((i == 4 or i == 5) and (d[4] == "X" or d[5] == "X")):
            score += 5
        
        print("Score is " + score +" woho")
```

And the Error is

```
   for i in t:
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

I am expecting the program to not show an Error and give me the score as given in the program

Comment: `for i in 10:` is not a thing. Did you mean `for i in range(10):` and `for i in range(t)`?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot iterate over an int, your object needs to be an iterable.

Just use this

`for i in range(t)`

range(t) returns an iterable containing the ints from 0 to t-1.

you can check more about the use of range in the Python docs.

Best of luck!

Comment: “range(t) returns a list containing the ints from 0 to t-1”. In fact range(t) returns a range object, which is iterable, but you can get a list by using list(range(t))